# flot plothover not work in ie9 and ie10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, flot

I have a chart

```
$.plot($("#placeholder2"), 
[ {label:'pulse', data: d11, color: '#3b5998'}], 
{grid:{hoverable: true}}
);

$("#placeholder2").bind("plothover", function (evt, position, item) {
     alert(item);
});
```

in IE9 and 10 item always = null
in other browsers and ie7-8 (with excanvas) item returns values

Comment: I just tested on IE9 and see no problems; can you show us what you're using for data?  Also, what jQuery version are you using?

Comment: Could also be that you're including excanvas for the newer IEs?

Comment: @Ryley excanvas I include in conditional comments [if lte IE 8]

Comment: @DNS i found something interesting. It works in ie9-10 if page not scroll. After scrolling page down it stops working.

Comment: https://github.com/flot/flot/issues/939#issuecomment-12637729